# How to output the python print result into a table or CSV format?

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to python and right now I'm trying to learn web scraping for personal travel planning. I would like to know after I print the result, how can I output it into a table format or CSV format.

right now the result goes like the following:

```
{'price': '115', 'name': 'The hotel name'}
{'price': '97', 'name': 'the hotel name'}
.......
```

I Googled the method of some modules like pandas and prettytable, find it is too much challenge for me to understand. So I am here to see if there is any solutions regarding my problem.

The code is as below:

```
import requests                   
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url="http://hotelname.com/arrivalDate=05%2F23%2F2016**&departureDate=05%2F24%2F2016" #means arrive on May23 and leaves on May 
wb_data = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(wb_data.text,'lxml')
names = soup.select('.PropertyName')
prices = soup.select('.RateSection ')
for name,price in zip(names,prices):    
    data = {
           "name":name.get_text(),
           "price":price.get_text()
            }
    print (data)`
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope your previous codes are right and the writing part;

```
import csv
with open('filename.csv', 'w') as csvfile:    #create csv file with w mode
    fieldnames = ['names', 'prices']          #header names
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fiel dnames)    #set the writer
    writer.writeheader()    
    for name,price in zip(names,prices):     #writing the elements 
        writer.writerow({'names': name.get_text(), 'prices': price.get_text()})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use pandas to create a DataFrame and then write the DataFrame to csv.
This would require a slight change to your dict to make it easier, the code could look something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

#...

data = {                                        
    0: {"name": name.get_text()},
    1: {"price": price.get_text()}
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
df.to_csv('filename.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to write to the file, where you are printing the values:

```
import requests
import csv

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url="http://hotelname.com/arrivalDate=05%2F23%2F2016**&departureDate=05%2F24%2F2016" #means arrive on May23 and leaves on May 
wb_data = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(wb_data.text,'lxml')
names = soup.select('.PropertyName')
prices = soup.select('.RateSection ')

with open('results.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(['Name', 'Price']]

    for name,price in zip(names,prices):
        writer.writerow([name.get_text(), price.get_text()])
```